# Generic Enum as a Parameter for a Picker SwiftUI iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, enums, picker

I am trying to create a entry field view that will accept any `enum` for a `Picker` (as long as that enum conforms to `CaseIterable` and `String`.

```
struct EntryFieldView<T: CaseIterable>: View where T.AllCases: RandomAccessCollection, T.AllCases.Element: Hashable & RawRepresentable, T.AllCases.Element.RawValue == String {
    @State var fieldTitle: String = ""
    @State var dropDownSelection: T
    @Binding var entry: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Group {
                if self.fieldTitle.isEmpty == false {
                    HStack {
                        Text(self.fieldTitle)
                            .font(.system(size: 10))
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(height: 40)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .shadow(radius: 2)
                    HStack {
                        Picker("Test", selection: self.$entry) {
                            ForEach(self.dropDownSelection.allCases, id: \.self) { selection in
                                Text(selection.rawValue)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 5)
                }
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 10)
        }
    }
}
```

And for example I have a simple list of countries:

```
enum Countries: String, CaseIterable {
    case UK = "United Kingdom"
    case USA = "United States of America"
    case ES = "Spain"
    case PL = "Poland"
    case DE = "Germany"
}
```

I get the error `Static member 'allCases' cannot be used on instance of type 'T'`
with the suggestion
`Static member 'allCases' cannot be used on instance of type 'T'`

If `dropDownSelection` is of Type `T` and `T` conforms to `CaseIterable`, why can't I use `dropDownSelection.allCases`, and why would it suggest I replace `dropDownSelection` with instance `T`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allCases` is a static member on the *type* `T`. `dropDownSelection` is a single case of that enum.

For example, let's remove the generic `T` and just your your example `Countries`. You could say `Countries.allCases` (note that `Countries` is a `Type`), but you would not do:

```
let country: Countries = .USA
let all = country.allCases // Error
```